# thinning out data in pandas/python to get best possible "even" distribution

Tags: python, pandas

**Task definition**

- Given: set of unique float values (size=`N`)
- Find: sub-set of fixed size `K`, where min/max values of original set are included, but other `K-2` values are ***distributed as evenly as possible***
- Example: when `N=51`, and the set consists of unique integer values between 0 and 50, and `K=6`, then the desired sub-set would be `{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}`

**Challenges**

In fact, the original set often represents uneven distribution. It can be something like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 19, 37, 50}`. Because of it:

1. approach with taking each i-th value will not work (where
   `i=(N-1)/(K-1)`) - I need to take both 19 and 37 in my example
2. approach with finding "ideal" values `{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}` first and then closest to them will not allow simple implementation (37 is closest to both 30 and 40 in my example)

I think I understand how I can extend the second solution to implement it.
But I wonder if my task can be reduced to some standard task, so that I can use existing functionality of python or pandas. I would appreciate any advise on it.

It can be formulated in generic way that I am trying ***to minimize the deviation of difference between two adjacent values of ordered K-subset: K(i) - K(i-1)***

Comment: It is hard to identify what you want to do. What is `K-2`? What is the subset `{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}`? You have to calrify your question.

Comment: `K-2` is the number of values which I need to select to make the desired sub-set as evenly distributed as possible.

The total size of that sub-set is `K`, but because it has to include min and max values of original set (size `N`), then final task is actually about selecting remaining `K-2` values only

Comment: Sub-set `{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}` would be the best possible answer if original set included all integers from 0 to 50: `{0, 1, 2, .., 48, 49, 50}`